# ARM assembly hex multiplication

Tags: assembly, hex, arm

Can anyone please explain the following to me?

The following is a minimum length ARM instruction sequence that multiplies R1 times the constant `0x0110 003F` without using a multiply instruction

```
ADD r2, r1, r1, LSL #4      //r2 = 0x11 * r1
RSB r3, r1, r1, LSL #6      //r3 = 0x3F * r1
ADD r3, r3, r2, LSL #20     //r3 = 0x0110 003F * r1
```

I'm not sure why `0x11` and `0X3F` are used to get `0x0110 003F`

Can anyone familiar with ARM architecture or hex please explain this procedure for me? Why is RSB used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The math has nothing to do with ARM...

```
ADD r2,r1,r1, LSL #4    r2 = r1 + (r1 << 4);
RSB r3,r1,r1, LSL #6    r3 = (r1 << 6) - r1;
ADD r3,r3,r2, LSL #20   r3 = r3 + (r2 << 20);
```

Remember multiplication from grade school?

```
  123
 x 12
=====
  246
+123
=====
 1476
```

Now the really cool thing about multiplication in binary is that you either multiply the number by 1 or 0 for each column (power of 2).  In the decimal math above the ones column, base (10) to the power 0, has a 2 in it.  In binary (base 2) we wont have that.  for the tens column (base to the power 1) that is like what we will see in binary, take the top number and multiply it by base to the power 1 (shift left one position) and add/accumulate that to the result.

So if I wanted, in base 2 (binary) to multiply something by 0b1011, I have bits 3, 1, and 0 set so,

```
result = (x<<3) + (x<<1) + (x<<0);
```

to multiply by 0x0110003F, we could do an add for each of the 8 bits

```
result = (r1<<24)+(r1<<20)+(r1<<5)...
```

but we can use more basic math.

```
rx * 0x3F
0x3F = 0x40 -1
rx * 0x3F = rx * (0x40 - 1)
distribute
rx * 0x3F = (rx * 0x40) - (rx * 1)
rx * 0x3F = (rx * 0x40) - rx
we know from the comments above that
rx * 0x40 = rx << 6
rx * 0x3F = (rx << 6) - rx
```

Now

```
ADD r2,r1,r1,lsl 4    r2 = r1 + (r1 << 4) 

r2 = r1 + (r1 << 4)
r2 = r1 + (r1 * 0x10)
r2 = (r1 * 1) + (r1 * 0x10)
r2 = r1 * (1 + 0x10)
r2 = r1 * 0x11
```

so

```
r3 = r1 * 0x3F 
r2 = r1 * 0x11
```

the last step is

```
result = r3 + (r2<<20)
result = (r1 * 0x3F) + ((r1*0x11)<<20)
result = (r1 * 0x3F) + ((r1*0x11)*0x100000)
result = (r1 * 0x3F) + (r1*0x1100000)
result = r1 * (0x3f + 0x1100000)
result = r1 * 0x110003F
```

The reason why reverse subtract is used is because to perform

```
r3 = (r1 << 6) - r1
```

with ARM instructions can be done a couple of ways:

```
mov r3,r1,lsl 6  r3 = (r1 << 6)
sub r3,r3,r1     r3 = r3 - r1
```

or

```
rsb r3,r1,r1,lsl 6   r3 = (r1 << 6) - r1
```

rsb just means reverse subtract, a normal subtract

```
sub ra,rb,rc means ra = rb - rc
```

reverse subtract means reverse the order of the operands

```
rsb ra,rb,rc means ra = rc - rb
```

to do a shift on an operand on arm for three register formats like this, it has to be the last operand so if you want the left operand of your subtract shifted, then use rsb.

```
sub ra,rb,rc,lsl x means ra = rb - (rc << x)
rsb ra,rb,rc,lsl x means ra = (rc << x) - rb
```

We wanted the rsb form to save an instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your lines in pseudocode (and decimals):

```
r2 = r1 + (r1 <<4) == r1 * 16 + r1 == r1 * 17
r3 = r1 << 6 - r1 = r1 * 64 - r1 = r1 * 63
r3 = r3 + r2 << 20 = r3 + r2 * 1048576
```

Substituting lines 1 and 2 into 3:

```
r3 = (r1 * 63) + 1048576 * (17 * r1) = r1 * (63 + 17825792) = r1 * 17825855
```

... And `17825855` in hex is `110003F`!

To answer the question as to why these numbers are used, it's going to be related to [Peasant Multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Peasant_or_binary_multiplication) and the decomposition into shifts and adds. Your constant value of `110003F` is actually this:

(2<sup>4</sup> + 1) * 2<sup>20</sup> + 2<sup>6</sup> - 1

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with C, here's a line-by-line translation (using variables instead of registers):

```
r2 = r1 + (r1 << 4);
r3 = (r1 << 6) - r1;
r3 = r3 + (r2 << 20);
```

Recall that `r1 << 4` is the same as `r1 * 16`, so the first line says `r2 = r1 + r1*16`, or `r2 = r1*17`.

Similarly, `r1 << 6` is `r1 * 64`, so the second line says `r3 = r1 * 64 - r1`, or `r3 = r1*63`.

Following the same pattern, the final line says `r3 = r3 + r2 * 1048576`, which, substituting the values from the previous lines, is `r3 = r1*63 + r1*17*1048576`. That simplifies to `r3 = 17825855 * r1`, or `r3 = 0x0110003f * r1`.